# What is the appropiate iommu kernel parameter for Ryzen5 1600 and multiple RX580 GPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, amd-graphics, amd, iommu

Reserving all the PCIe slot for RX580 prevents my PC to boot, due to such errors `AMD-VI IOTLB_INV_TIMEOUT`, `AER: Corrected error received` or kernel panic. Adding the linux parameters with `iommu=soft` and `pci=noaer` solves the boot issue. On Lubuntu and Ubuntu 20.04 I see these logs from the kernel drm:

```
00:58:47 lubu kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
00:58:47 lubu kernel: [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
00:58:47 lubu kernel: [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
00:58:47 lubu kernel: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
```

Additionally, on Ubuntu 20.04, the gdm3 floods my journalctl with such messages:

```
14:02:36 ub20 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1334]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 19311
14:02:36 ub20 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1334]: (II) AMDGPU(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: 720x480 Warning: We only handle separate sync.
14:02:36 ub20 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1334]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
14:02:36 ub20 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1334]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
14:02:36 ub20 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1334]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
```

However, if I use the GPU extensively, I experience a random system freeze, in both distributions. If I check the journalctl mostly, I see such error logs:

```
00:59:06 lubu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=175, emitted seq=177
00:59:06 lubu kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
00:59:06 lubu kernel: amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
30 00:59:06 lubu kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] 
                              last message was failed ret is 65535
```

or

```
kernel: [drm:amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!
kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=4226, emitted seq=4228
```

Some Linux user reported that `iommu=pt` solves such a problem, see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250297.

I've been confused since several months with this issue, I would like to learn and understand deeply, what is going on here. Thus, I've read the Linux kernel documentation reagarding the iIOMMU tuning in https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html for the possible parameter and the meaning of the parameter in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt.

Since I'm not an IOMMU expert and it is difficult to me to understand the terms, such as GART, re/unmapping, bounch buffering (SWIOTLB) and the interaction between amdgpu and the Linux system itself. I can read: `iommu=soft` means that Linux uses software bounce buffering (SWIOTLB), and the default value `noforce` prevents the OS boot on my PC. `noforce` means that the hardware IOMMU is not forced to use.

Then, there is another parameter, called `amd_iommu` which is of course significant for my hardware setup.  This option has three possible values to be assigned: fullflush, off, force_isolation. Unfortunately, I don't know what is the default value of this option.

My short question would be: what is the best combination of the parameters `iommu` and `amd_iommu` for my hardware to have a fully utilization of my RX580s on Ryzen5?

My extra questions:

1. is `amd_iommu` complements the `iommu`? or does `amd_iommu` refer to the AMD Ryzen CPU or the AMD GPU hardware? If there is also `intel_iommu`, I think `amd_iommu` refers to the Ryzen chipset.
2. if `iommu` is not forced to use hardware IOMMU, what is the impact of `amd_iommu = off`?

I will be very grateful to read more deep explanation and a direct link to the source code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the general VESA drivers?

Comment: no, I didn't know about that. I only installed the OpenCL driver with `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`. How can I install and try the VESA drivers?

Comment: Have you tried running `apt install vesa` or `apt install xserver-xorg-video-vesa`?

Comment: @SirMuffington shall I also install the amdgpu driver from https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20?

Comment: give it a go then. Did you try installing the VESA drivers first though?

Comment: `xserver-xorg-video-vesa` has been already installed from the distributor. `sudo apt install vesa` doesn't work.